# Subsetting a data frame by a value of one of its colums

Tags: r, subset

I have a rather large data frame. Here is a simplified example:

```
Group Element Value Note
1     AAA     11    Good
1     ABA     12    Good
1     AVA     13    Good
2     CBA     14    Good
2     FDA     14    Good
3     JHA     16    Good
3     AHF     16    Good
3     AKF     17    Good
```

Here it is as a `dput`:

```
dat <- structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Element = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("AAA", "ABA", "AHF", 
"AKF", "AVA", "CBA", "FDA", "JHA"), class = "factor"), Value = c(11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 16L, 16L, 17L), Note = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Good", class = "factor")), .Names = c("Group", 
"Element", "Value", "Note"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

I'm trying to separate it based on the group. so let's say

Group 1 will be a data frame:

```
Group Element Value Note
1     AAA     11    Good
1     ABA     12    Good
1     AVA     13    Good
```

Group 2:

```
2     CBA     14    Good
2     FDA     14    Good
```

and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `split` for this.

```
> dat
##   Group Element Value Note
## 1     1     AAA    11 Good
## 2     1     ABA    12 Good
## 3     1     AVA    13 Good
## 4     2     CBA    14 Good
## 5     2     FDA    14 Good
## 6     3     JHA    16 Good
## 7     3     AHF    16 Good
## 8     3     AKF    17 Good

> x <- split(dat, dat$Group)
```

Then you can access each individual data frame by group number with `x[[1]]`, `x[[2]]`, etc.
For example, here is group 2:

```
> x[[2]]  ## or x[2]
##   Group Element Value Note
## 4     2     CBA    14 Good
## 5     2     FDA    14 Good
```

**ADD:** Since you asked about it in the comments, you can write each individual data frame to file with `write.csv` and `lapply`.  The `invisible` wrapper is simply to suppress the output of `lapply`

```
> invisible(lapply(seq(x), function(i){
      write.csv(x[[i]], file = paste0(i, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)
  }))
```

We can see that the files were created by looking at `list.files`

```
> list.files(pattern = "^[0-9].csv")
## [1] "1.csv" "2.csv" "3.csv"
```

And we can see the data frame of the third group with `read.csv`

```
> read.csv("3.csv")
##   Group Element Value Note
## 1     3     JHA    16 Good
## 2     3     AHF    16 Good
## 3     3     AKF    17 Good
```

Comment: Thank you. How do I create new data frames from the split?

Comment: They're already created as elements of the list.  Assign a variable, say `x`, to `split(D, D$Group)`.  Then you can access each individual data frame by group number with `x[[1]]`, `x[[2]]`, etc. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: is there a possibility of writing those two data frames to two different files, with default names of 1.csv, 2.csv and so on?

Comment: To create new data frames from the split, [`list2env`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/list2env.html) might be handy.

Comment: How would you treat the same task if the Group values were characters?

Comment: It should work the same either way. `split` as used above will split by the unique values in `Group`.

Answer (score 1):

Obligatory `plyr` version (pretty much equiv to Richard's, but I'll bet it's slower, too:

```
library(plyr)

groups <- dlply(dat, .(Group), function(x) { return(x) })

length(groups)
## [1] 3

groups$`1` # can also do groups[[1]]
##   Group Element Value Note
## 1     1     AAA    11 Good
## 2     1     ABA    12 Good
## 3     1     AVA    13 Good

groups[[2]]
##   Group Element Value Note
## 1     2     CBA    14 Good
## 2     2     FDA    14 Good
```